# How to setup a workspace wide configuration for Java Compiler Annotation Processing

Tags: java, eclipse, annotations

In project properties I can go to

Java Compiler > Annotation Processing > Factory Path

and point to my jar file and everything is fine, but it's something I have to do for each project (and I have many and am constantly adding/deleting projects).  That configuration path isn't available at the workspace level and I'm wondering if there is another way to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should be using Maven (with the Eclipse m2e plugin), and configuring the annotation processing in each project's POM files ... or in a common parent POM file.

[This page](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/index.html) describes how to configure Maven's Java compiler plugin, and [this one](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html) lists the attributes you can set in the POM file.

Comment: We're using maven and the annotation processor is configured in the pom.  I don't want to build with maven in eclipse, I would prefer to configure the annotation processor in eclipse and was hoping to find a way to do it workspace wide.

Comment: Are you using m2eclipse?  In theory, that should copy the compiler settings from the POM file into the Eclipse project settings when you configure the project.

Comment: We are using m2eclipse, and I agree in theory, but it doesn't appear to be happening that way in practice.  I've pretty much given up on this one and am configuring at the project level.

Comment: @digitaljoel - if this is a significant pain point, consider developing a PATCH for m2eclipse to do the right thing.  Or at least, submit a bug report / feature request.

Comment: I haven't taken the time to verify 100% that it's an m2eclipse problem and not our problem. Unfortunately, some teams have checked in the .project, .settings, .classpath files/directories for their project, so it could be that they just don't have it setup correctly.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, M2Eclipse doesn't handle natively the annotation processing phase.

To make up for this lack, there is the [Maven Integration for Eclipse JDT Annotation Processor Toolkit plugin](https://github.com/jbosstools/m2e-apt) provided by JBoss Tools team that handles annotation processing with M2Eclipse.

Explanations of how it works are given in the readme part of the GitHub page and in [this blog post](https://community.jboss.org/community/tools/blog/2012/05/20/annotation-processing-support-in-m2e-or-m2e-apt-100-is-out). Get a careful reading of the aforedmentioned blog post to understand the configuration.